# Close a XtraUserControl on esc key pressed

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a class

```
MyWindows : XtraUserControl,ISmartPartInfoProvider
```

And I want to close it when the escape key is pressed.

I use Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.SmartParts MyWindows for displaying the windows as followed:
    MyWindows temp = new MyWindows(); 
    myWorkspace.Show(temp);

I try the following :

In the constructor

```
PreviewKeyDown += OnKeyDownP;
KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
```

With the method :

```
    private void OnKeyDownP(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

But no event is trigerred.

did I missed something?

**EDIT**
This Post was usefull for me :
[Close a XtraUserControl on esc key pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662846/close-a-xtrausercontrol-on-esc-key-pressed)

Comment: How/where are you showing the usercontrol? Usually the focused control will receive the key event handlers and not the form.

Comment: Hello, I use Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.SmartParts

    MyWindows : XtraUserControl,ISmartPartInfoProvider

Then I do 
    MyWindows temp = new MyWindows();
    myWorkspace.Show(temp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should set the `KeyPreview` property of your `Form` to `true`. And you should use your `Form` events to catch key pressing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not see such property in DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl.

Comment: Is there any form, that hosts this control? What does it have in `Parent` property?

Comment: Yes he have a Parent property, because XtraUserControl inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Control.

Comment: I asked what it contains in this property? MyWorkspace? And then what MyWorkspace contains in its `Parent` property? I assume, that there is a form on the top of all this.

Comment: this.Parent = DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking.ControlContainer

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ29309.aspx here is the same advice from DevExpress Support, but with a note  "Unfortunately however, I don't think you will be able to implement this task in this manner."

Comment: Hello,
I did `var parentForm = this.ParentForm;
            if (parentForm != null) {parentForm.KeyPreview = true;}` and it works, thank you for helping me!